# Grouping Model class into other Model with RxJava

Tags: android, list, rx-java, android-room

I am working with the Android Room Persistence Library, which returns a Flowable of List of MyModel (`Flowable<List<MyModel>>`). `MyModel` has the function `getMonth`which returns a integer.

I am trying to group MyModel's into MyModelWrapper which is a wrapper class for a List of MyModel and the integer (`MyModelWrapper(int month, List<MyModel>)`).

The code should group the List of `MyModel` `MyModel(0)`, `MyModel(0)`, `MyModel(1)`, `MyModel(2)` into a List of `MyModelWrapper` `MyModelWrapper(0, List(MyModel(0), MyModel(0))`, `MyModelWrapper(1, List(MyModel(1))` and `MyModelWrapper(2, List(MyModel(2))`.

My current code which is not using RxJava

```
List<MyModel> models = database.myModelDao().getMyModels();

Map<Integer, List<MyModel>> orderedData = new HashMap<>();
for(MyModel model : models) {
    if(orderedData.get(model.getMonth()) == null) {
        orderedData.put(model.getMonth(), new ArrayList<MyModel>());
    }
    orderedData.get(model.getMonth()).add(model);
}

final ArrayList<MyModelWrapper> recordedModels = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<MyModel>> cursor : recordedModels.entrySet()) {
    List<MyModel> myModelRecords = cursor.getValue();
    MyModelWrapper modelWrapper = new MyModelWrapper()
        .setMyModels(myModelRecords)
        .setMonth(cursor.getKey());
    recordedModels.add(modelWrapper);
}

return recordedModels;
```

**How would I RxIfy this?**

I tried getting the first Element from the `Flowable` with `first()`, the `groupBy()` my key but that is returning a `GroupedObservable` which would somehow be turned into a list, then transformed into a List to be converted to MyModelWrapper.

Any help is appreciated!

---

**Solution I ended up using:**

```
getMyModelsFlowable()
    .flatMapIterable(new Function<List<MyModel>, Iterable<MyModel>>() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<MyModel> apply(List<MyModel> models) throws Exception {
            return models;
        }
    }).groupBy(new Function<MyModel, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer apply(MyModel model) throws Exception {
            return model.getMonth();
        }
    }).flatMapSingle(new Function<GroupedFlowable<Integer, MyModel>, SingleSource<MyModelWrapper>>() {
        @Override
        public SingleSource<MyModelWrapper> apply(final GroupedFlowable<Integer, MyModel> group) throws Exception {
            return group.toList().map(new Function<List<MyModel>, MyModelWrapper>() {
                @Override
                public MyModelWrapper apply(List<MyModel> models) throws Exception {
                    return new MyModelWrapper()
                            .setMyModels(models)
                            .setMonth(group.getKey());
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: you can use lambda expression to make it more concise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach with `GroupedFlowable` is correct.
Consider this test snippet

```
@Test
fun modelWrap() {
    val data = Flowable.just(listOf(
            Model(1, "1"), 
            Model(2, "2"), 
            Model(1, "3"), 
            Model(3, "4")))
    val modelsByMonth = data.flatMapIterable { it }.groupBy { it.month }
    val wrappedModels = modelsByMonth
            .flatMapSingle { group ->
                group.toList().map { modelsList -> WrappedModel(group.key, modelsList) }
            }
    val wrappedModelsList = wrappedModels.toList()
    val wrappedModelsVal = wrappedModelsList.blockingGet()
    Assert.assertNotNull(wrappedModelsVal)
    Assert.assertEquals(3, wrappedModelsVal.size)

}

data class Model(val month: Int, val data: String)
data class WrappedModel(val month: Int?, val data: List<Model>)
```

It produces output

`[WrappedModel(month=1, data=[Model(month=1, data=1), Model(month=1, data=3)]), 
 WrappedModel(month=2, data=[Model(month=2, data=2)]), 
 WrappedModel(month=3, data=[Model(month=3, data=4)])]`

I think you are mostly interested how `wrappedModels` val is constructed

Comment: example is written in kotlin - was sure I saw the tag in question. If there is confusion i'll rewrite it in java

Comment: Thank you, this solution works. I guess the operators just take some time getting used to / learned...

Answer (score 0):

One of the RxJava implementation of your given code snippet can be done into following way:

```
Single.<List<MyModel>>create(subscriber -> {
        List<MyModel> models = database.myModelDao().getMyModels();
        subscriber.onSuccess(models);
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).map(models -> {
        Map<Integer, List<MyModel>> orderedData = new HashMap<>();
        for(MyModel model : models) {
            if(orderedData.get(model.getMonth()) == null) {
                orderedData.put(model.getMonth(), new ArrayList<MyModel>());
            }
            orderedData.get(model.getMonth()).add(model);
        }
        final ArrayList<MyModelWrapper> recordedModels = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<MyModel>> cursor : recordedModels.entrySet()) {
            List<MyModel> myModelRecords = cursor.getValue();
            MyModelWrapper modelWrapper = new MyModelWrapper()
                    .setMyModels(myModelRecords)
                    .setMonth(cursor.getKey());
            recordedModels.add(modelWrapper);
        }
        return recordedModels;
    }).subscribe(recordedModels -> {
        // this is where you get your converted list
    }, error -> {
        // handle exception if any
    });
```

I can't see any returned `Flowable` in your code that you mentioned in your question. Check the given example and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: how is this answer related to rx way of doing things?

Comment: @m.ostroverkhov this is what i thought he want to ask. If do you think this is not right way please correct me. you are most welcome.

Comment: I think OP's intention was to avoid imperative boilerplate code (creating lists, iterating over them and transforming manually), and instead use set of some rx operators instead

Comment: @m.ostroverkhov thanks to notice it. I am still learning RxJava. I just saw you answer and just learn some on new operators that i didn't know thanks buddy. But i think asker might not know `kotlin` and wont understand it. I think you should convert it to Java i guess.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, like @m.ostroverkhov said, I wanted to get rid of the manual assigning. See OP for my final solution.